# configuring and using ispell

Tags: auctex, ispell

I have been able to install Emacs 25.1 and AUCTeX 11.89.6 (this is the number that I have after installing it with MELPA directly from Emacs) that I am using on a Windows 7 machine. 
I am trying to use ispell possibly with flyspell but when I type
M-x flyspell-mode
I get: Error enabling flysepll 
(Searching for program No such file or directory ispell)
I have tryied adding
(require 'ispell)
(setq ispell-program-name "ispell")
and
(setq ispell-program-name "tex-ispell")
I have read that ispell comes with Emacs 25 and I have found isepll.el in the emacs directory. I have also checked that I have that directory on the Emacs path by
C-h v load-path
Finally, I have tried to "launch" directly from with emacs in the customization menu but failed.
It seems like an easy task but I am not being able to make it work.
Any pointer would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to install it on your system. Here's the page: https://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell.html

If you're on OS X you can just install it with [homebrew](http://brew.sh): `brew install ispell`

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Unfortunately, I am on windows 7 at work. Is there any ispell binaries for win 64bits, I have looked but the closest I found was a win32 from here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/what-is-the-relationship-between-emacs-and-various-spellcheckers-ispell-etc

Comment: unfortunately I'm not a windows user, so I'm not going to be of much help. You might also check whether `aspell` is available for windows. that might be just as good. There's a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2020810/6277148).