# Spell checking and hunspell on windows (preferably from scratch)

Tags: microsoft-windows, ispell, hunspell

I really need to get spellchecker on emacs (there are few who don't), and hunspell seems like the best option. The other options (aspell and ispell) are said to be ancient and also require a fair amount of configuration, so I figure there is no benefit to using those. Most instructions tell you to get a 4-year old pre-compiled 32-bit hunspell binary from ezwinports, though I've heard that it no longer works (and may not even be compatible with 64 bit emacs). So I'd like to compile it from the newest source from scratch.

I already have compiled hunspell for windows 10 x64 using msys2, per instructions from  [hunspell](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell). All I have now is just the **DLL** and no dictionaries or executables. Does anyone know where to go from here to set up spell checking? I've seen the instructions on how to modify the .emacs file, but none seem tell you how to actually what a hunspell installation ought to look like. (and I don't see anything along the lines of "point Emacs to the .dll; then point emacs to the dictionaries directory).

p.s. does anyone know why this is so difficult? :)

-- thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Since you're using Msys2, why not installing their version with `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-hunspell RET`?  Set up their version (1.4.1) with Emacs, once it's working, you can go on and try to compile the new version yourself.  P.S. I have a working setup with Msys2 hunspell & Emacs, it wasn't that hard getting it runnig `:-)`.

Comment: Here is a related thread entitled "**What is the relationship between Emacs and various spellcheckers (ispell, etc.)?**":  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/what-is-the-relationship-between-emacs-and-various-spellcheckers-ispell-etc

Comment: thanks. hunspell works now. but emacs spell-checking is not usable. opening another question: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30008/hunspell-and-emacs-on-windows